# redirecting page based on own url

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect my page based on my url. e.g. if i visit www.home.com I want to redirect it to www.home.com/home. I have a code but it has some bugs on my site.

Below is the code I'm using now i want this JS to only activate if I put www.home.com how can i incorporate that to this JS?

JS:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href="http://home.com/"; // The URL that will be redirected too.
    }, 0); // The bigger the number the longer the delay.
</script>
```

UPDATE:

```
 <script>
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.location.href;

if (a.hostname.replace('http://www.', '') == 'frederiksminde.com') {

    window.location.href = 'http://www.frederiksminde.com/da/';

}
  </script>
```

This codes works fine but when i visit the sub pages of http://www.frederiksminde.com/da/ it also redirects me to the frederiksminde.com/da/

Comment: check if window.location.href matches home.com using a simple if condition inside setTimeout

Comment: i don't know how to code that sir. i just copy that from some threads. sorry

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment from unikorn:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (window.location.href=="http://www.home.com"){
            window.location.href = "http://www.home.com/home"
        }
    }, 0); // The bigger the number the longer the delay.
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide the whole html code of your page containing the script-tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
           if(window.location.href == "http://www.home.com"){ //window.location.href returns current page url 
              window.location.href="http://www.home.com/home";
           }
        }, 0); // The bigger the number the longer the delay.
  </script>
```

in the above code if condition check current url is www.home.com or www.home.com/home

it will redirects to other page.

Comment: if i put home.com i should go to the /home if its work but it stays on the home.com... i think the window location need to get the value on its own not using the "== "http://home.com")"

Comment: this check is for conforming that user is on http://home.com. if the user is in http://home.com then, he will redirect /home. I think your using jquery,try to put this block of code in ready function()

Comment: what do you mean can you edit the answer instead. I'm not good at coding JS/JQuery

Answer (score 0):

get just the beginning part of your URL, plus 'home'

```
<script>
document.ondomcontentready = function () {
    var slice = location.href.split('/');
    var domain = slice[1] ? slice[0] : slice[2];
    var final = domain + '/home';
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = final;
    }
    }, 0);
}
</script>
```

Put the  tag wherever you need the link.

Answer (score 0):

Let the browser do the work and just check for hostname:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.location.href;

if (a.hostname.replace('www.', '') == 'host.com') {

    window.location.href = 'host.com/home';

}
```

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

So according to the ref you also just could use the `window.location.hostname`, but I wanted to show you the might of an `a`-Tag if you just take the `href`-part, you can use it like `a.href.hostname` too.

I wanted to provide a JSFiddle example, but JSFiddle is not saving right now. If you want to try this at JSFiddle, use following code:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.location.href;

if (a.hostname.replace('fiddle.', '') == 'jshell.net') {

    window.location.href = 'host.com/home';

}
```

The reason I use a little different code is, because JSFiddle uses 'fiddle.jshell.net' as URL, so the `fiddle.` part will be removed and just the main part checked and if it's jshell, it will redirect and it's working, but 'home.com/home' don't exist, it's just a example domain so it's obviously not showing any relevant content.

**EDIT**

I found out some in-depth information.

If you don't have `http://` inside the href, it will take the `window.location`, so be careful if you using this technic with a other given `href`.

Also I added a `pathname` check, so it's not redirecting if it's the redirected page.

Following the code without the `a`-Tag part (because it's not needed here):

```
if (window.location.hostname.replace( 'www.', '' ) == 'host.com' && window.location.pathname.replace( '/', '' ).length == 0 ) {
    window.location.href = 'host.com/home';
}
```

instead of `replace( '/', '' )` you also could use `replace( /\/(.*)?/g, '' )` if you have more than just one word after the first `/` like `home/login/now`.

Comment: the redirect work but on a different page from the site not sure what did that...

Comment: Did you changed the `host.com/home` part inside `window.location.href` to YOUR actually url?

Comment: its works but for the subpages of the /home it also redirects also the condition work on all links under the condition... reupload the script on my question

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle of the EXACT Code you made and also give us the EXACT Domain you have? Just click once, so it automatically selects everything, than Copy+Paste it.